# error while "npm install" command in windows

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, npm-install

I have installed `nodejs v4.4.5LTS` and run command line and below error is occurs. please help me

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600  
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\  
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"  
npm ERR! node v6.2.2  
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.5  
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE  
npm ERR! angular-seed@0.0.0 prestart: `npm install`  
npm ERR! Exit status 1  
npm ERR!  
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-seed@0.0.0 prestart script 'npm install'.  
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.  
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-seed package,  

npm ERR! not with npm itself.  
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:  
npm ERR!     npm install  
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:  
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-seed  
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:  
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-seed  
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.  

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:  
npm ERR!     C:\xampp\htdocs\angular\npm-debug.log  

C:\xampp\htdocs\angular>
```

Comment: It's seems to search the version angular-seed of angular-seed. Could you share with us your package.json ?

Comment: Are you sure it was just a `npm install` and not a `npm start` ? https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/issues/199